# how to get unixtimestamp from string in c++

Tags: c++

I am dealling with this problem few days allready, I´ve searched and tried everything that I found and nothing works. I want to change string in date format like this : 02.04.2016 to unix timestamp (seconds from year 1970) and nothing gives mi the result I need. I am allready getting actual time in seconds like this

```
time_t pom;
time(&pom);
```

Or I tried

```
time_t t = time(0);
```

but when I give the date of actual day (in string format) to the methods which I found that should be able to convert it to unixtimestamp or atleast something close to it, it gives me absolutly diferrent results than this method´s actual time and I am really driving crazy right here.. I also tried to wrote my own method to convert date to seconds, something like this :

```
 int Velkoslad::konvertujNaSekundy(std::string datum)
{
    int datumy[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31 , 30, 31 , 31, 30 , 31, 30 ,31 };
    std::string datumD = datum;
    long long dni = std::stoi(datumD.substr(0, 2));
    long long mesiace = std::stoi(datumD.substr(3, 2));
    long long rok = std::stoi(datumD.substr(6, 4));
    long long sekundaDni = dni * 86400;
    long long mesiaceSek = 0;

    if (mesiace == 2) {    //18748800,2419200,10368000
        if (rok % 4 == 0)
            mesiaceSek = (datumy[(mesiace - 1)] + 1) * 86400;
        else
            mesiaceSek = datumy[(mesiace - 1)] * 86400;
    }
    else
        mesiaceSek = datumy[(mesiace - 1)] * 86400;

    long long rokSek = 0;
    if (rok % 4 == 0)
        rokSek = ((rok - 1970) * 28857600) + 86400;
    else
        rokSek = (rok - 1970) * 28857600;

    long long datumVsec = 0;
    datumVsec += sekundaDni + mesiaceSek + rokSek;
    return datumVsec;
}
```

but this gives me bad results as well, or maybe I am getting bad actual time from that time method or somethig...
I really don´t know and I really tried to find something... I woul be very thankfull for every help..

Comment: If your platform have s [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) function it should be easy. It should also handle leap-years and (more importantly) leap seconds correctly.

Comment: Also you may want to look at [std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).